# Connection between operator overloading and JVM processing

Tags: java, operator-overloading

I need an expert review on this statement. I encountered this statement during my recent java interview.

> Adding Operator overloading to java would have definitely made design
>   more complex than without it, and it might have lead to more complex
>   compiler or slows the JVM .

justify this ?

1. From the above lines i have got 2 questions , how it could slow down the  jvm if assume there was operator overloading support in java , because overloading is being resolved during compile time , and jvm is all about run time perspective (correct me if i am wrong at this) .
2. by making complex compilers we can have more freedom of business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

(1) Overloading is not always resolvable at compile time. Subclasses may override methods and you do not know whether you have a parent or child class until the code executes. We don't know how operator overloading would have been implemented, but it would probably have the same behaviour.

(2) I don't think this is generally true. Adding operator overloading (essentially *syntactic sugar*) does not allow you to have more business logic. It may *express it* more succinctly, but it's the same logic. Consider the following code, where `a`, `b` and `c` are instances of the same class (ie. they're not scalars). The logic is the same, but some will prefer a different expression of it.

```
c = a.plus(b);
c = a + b;
```